# Configuration issue with Spring Boot OpenId Connect and Gluu

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, gluu

I'm trying to get a POC working with Gluu.  I followed the tutorial on https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ and got it working with facebook.  I then tried to move it over to gluu.  Made it through a couple issues with another article on stackoverflow, but now I'm getting this error.
`{
        "error": "invalid_request_redirect_uri",
        "error_description": "The redirect_uri in the Authorization Request 
        does not match any of the Client's pre-registered redirect_uris.",
        "state": "RexEdf"
    }`

application.yml: 

    `security:
      oauth2:
        client:
          clientId: "<my client id>"
          clientSecret: <my client secret>
          accessTokenUri: https://<gluu server>/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/token
          userAuthorizationUri: https://<gluu server>/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/authorize
          tokenName: oauth_token
          authenticationScheme: form
          clientAuthenticationScheme: form
          scope: openid
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://<gluu server>/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/authorize`

I've tried many options in gluu and on the boot client trying to get through this, but nothing seems to work.  I'm assuming this is a simple fix but I'm not able to find any useful info on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a co-worker look over it with me and we found a miss-entered redirect url.  Now I'm on to the next problem.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, in addition to adding the redirect uri to the `client` in Gluu, we had go to the `sector identifier` section and for the specific client we added a new entry for Redirect Login Uri

[image: Sector Nav]